# \footnote doesn't work with \twocolumn

Tags: footnotes, two-column, article

I am writing an article and need footnotes to write author affiliations. I am writing in a two-column format, and using `\twocolumn`, but adding `\footnote` inside this environment doesn't produce a footnote at the bottom. See this example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
\begin{center}
Author\footnote{This doesn't work.}
\end{center}
]

Text\footnote{This works.}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in most classes you can use `\thanks` rather than `\footnote` and it takes care of lifting the footnote out of the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext{}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
\begin{center}
Author\footnotemark
\end{center}
]\footnotetext{Now this works.}

Text\footnote{This works.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. Can I place a footnote linking to an already existing supersript, and make that particular superscript appear at the footnote?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. You can set the footnote counter to anything you want using `\setcounter{footnote}{x}`. Maybe ask a new question with your specifics and an example.